# regex match match numbers or number around colon but not after certain string

Tags: r, regex

For example I want to match numbers around `:`  but not if they fall within a parentheses.

```
str_extract( "2010:2012,mean(2010:2015)", '[0-9:0-9]+')
## 2010:2012 correct

str_extract( "mean(2010:2015),2010:2012", '[0-9:0-9]+')
## 2010:2015 incorrect
```

How can I check if there parentheses?

Comment: First of all `[0-9:0-9]+` is incorrect. It should be `[0-9]+:[0-9]+` and if you want to avoid string inside parentheses then use: `[0-9]+:[0-9]+(?![^()]*\))`

Comment: @anubhava need another backslash for escape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `[0-9:0-9]+` is not correct. As it matches 1 or more of a digit or colon. So it will match `123` or just `:` also.

Correction regex would be:

```
[0-9]+:[0-9]+
```

Now if you want to avoid string inside parentheses then use a negative lookahead (assuming all the parentheses are balanced and unescaped):

```
[0-9]+:[0-9]+(?![^()]*\))
```

`(?![^()]*\))` is a negative lookahead based condition that would fail the match is `number:number` is followed by a `)` without matching a `(` and `)`.

Note in `r` you will have use double escape it:

```
'[0-9]+:[0-9]+(?![^()]*\\))'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nfpwdy/1)